# Es el onCreate() asíncrono en un Servicio?

Tags: android

Estoy creando un servicio, y en la siguiente línea hago un evento el cual dicho servicio escucha,

```
startService(LocationService.getCallingIntent(mContext));

mBus.post(new OnGooogleApiConnected(mGoogleApiClient));
```

> ¿existe la posibilidad de que el servicio tarde más? Es decir, el
>   "start service" espera a que el servicio pase por el oncreate?

Answer (score -1):

Cuando inicias el servicio el primer método en llamarse es `onCreate()` y posteriormente `onStartCommand()`:

```
public class myService extends Service {

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        ...
        ...
    }

    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
       ...
       ...
    }

 }
```

De la documentación:

> [onCreate()](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html) El sistema llama a este método cuando se crea el
>   servicio por primera vez, para realizar los procedimientos de
>   configuración por única vez (antes de llamar a onStartCommand() o
>   onBind()). **Si el servicio ya se está ejecutando, no se llama a este
>   método.**

En cuanto a tu pregunta:

> ¿existe la posibilidad de que el servicio tarde más? Es decir, el
>   "start service" espera a que el servicio pase por el oncreate?

La primera vez que inicias el servicio necesariamente tiene que llamar `onCreate()` que toma el papel de inicializar/configurar el servicio, si tarda en iniciar tu servicio probablemente tienes algún proceso en este punto que provoca el problema.

Comment: Gracias, lo que me preocupa es que el servicio tarde "de forma asíncrona", para cuando el bus mande el evento el servicio todavía no este creado, es posible que suceda esto?